# Notification of Pending Tag Synonym suggestion

Tags: feature-request, notifications, tag-synonyms

How about notifying qualifying users when a new Tag Synonym suggestion is proposed?

It's hard to get enough people to vote on the tag synonyms, especially since they're well hidden.

Maybe a button that shows up on their homepage/questions page that links to [the suggested page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms) when there is a new one, or they are newly qualified.

[image]

EDIT: Ivo has a great idea, the notification could be a button/link that get's enabled on the [Review page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review).

[Related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60419/create-link-button-on-tags-page-to-go-to-tag-synonyms-page)

Comment: [Didn't we go over the inbox notification of new vote-able tag synonyms deal already](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76737/have-new-tag-synonyms-that-i-can-vote-for-show-up-in-the-stackexchange-multicoll)? Unless you can think of a non-inbox method here, this is a duplicate.

Comment: @Grace, I guess I just keep thinking of those same great ideas :).  I don't understand why the Team doesn't want to emphasize Tag Synonyms.  It's almost impossible to get enough people to vote on the not-so-popular tags.  I'll edit this question.

Comment: You would be better off suggesting it as an addition for the /Review page @Lance, at least the people there **care** about cleaning up the site.

Comment: @Ivo, that is a good idea, I'll edit my post.